# QVariant to QIcon/QPixmap/QImage

Tags: c++, qt, qvariant

I want to extract a QIcon I've stored in one of a QTreeWidget's columns, as Qt::DecorationRole.

```
QTreeWidgetItem *item = ui->treeWidget->topLevelItem(index);
const QIcon &icon = item->data(0, Qt::DecorationRole)._howToConvert_();
```

However, I can only get the data as QVariant, and I could not find a function to convert from a QVariant to QIcon. Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

OK, found the answer in [the docs for `QVariant`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qvariant.html#a-note-on-gui-types) upon further inspection.

This works:

```
QImage image = variant.value<QImage>();
```

Comment: In case you wonder: The same counts for any custom type you declare as a metatype and use in a user role.

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution as follows:

```
QImage name_image = table_store_multi_model_->item(i_row,0)->data(Qt::DecorationRole).value().toImage();
```

Generally, we read data with data(), but here need a parameter "Qt::DecorationRole";